# Оптимизация перебора всех элементов Dictionary<T,T>

Tags: c#, многопоточность, распараллеливание

Есть класс мира, в котором находится словарик форм жизни.
Каждый Update в классе мира вызывается foreach, который перебирает все формы жизни и производит с ними некоторые действия(изменение полей ботов, выполнение их методов и т.д.)

Также в цикле foreach может происходить **создание новых форм жизни, их удаление** и **занесение новых в перебираемый словарик**(!)

Код вы можете видеть ниже (значительно упрощённый):

```
public class LifeForm 
{
 // реализация класса формы жизни
}

public class World  
{
     Dictionary<long, LifeForm> LifeForms;

     private void Update()
     {
        foreach (LifeForm bot in LifeForms.Values.ToList())
        {
         // обновление данных бота,создание и добавление новых ботов в наш Dictionary
        }
    }
}
```

Одна итерация foreach проходит быстро и занимает примерно 1-2мс.
Но при 10000+ форм жизни в словарике на его обновление уходит более 5 секунд.

Само по себе обновление словарика в единичной итерации foreach требует очень мало ресурсов, можно ли одновременно обновлять сразу несколько элементов LifeForms?
Чем можно заменить классический foreach, чтобы перебор происходил в нескольких потоках?

Parallel.ForEach не даёт желаемого эффекта,с ним работает намного медленнее

Comment: Использовать `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: какая коллекция была изменена?

Comment: @Igor словарик LifeForms

Comment: Разве `LifeForms.Values.ToList()` не создает новый список? У Вас еще какой-то код, имеющий отношение к делу, который не показан в вопросе?

Comment: @Igor Ну есть методы,в которых меняется этот словарик,но все они вызываются вне Update мира.

Comment: Я мало что понимаю в вашем вопросе. Зачем вы используете Dictionary как List?

Comment: @Zergatul у каждого бота есть id,по которому он доступен в словаре

Comment: Если вам нужно часто обновлять 10000 элементов, то 1мс на каждый - это очень долго! Ищите способы ускорения тела цикла.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov ускорить тело цикла никак не получится....

Comment: Попробуйте разбить ваш словарь на несколько более мелких и обработать в несколько потоков, потом собрать обратно, ну или использовать ConcurrentDictionary например и также обрабатывать в нескольких потоках, поэкспериментируйте.

Comment: Все-таки непонятно, почему именно Dictionary используется? Ведь у вас идет постоянный перебор _всех_ элементов коллекции. Для этого лучше взять List. Добавление в него тоже очень быстрое. Правда, удаление из середины/начала намного хуже.